# Wait on the database engine recovery handle failed

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to install sql server 2008 r2 at my local machine and at the end of the installation i got this error "Wait on the database engine recovery handle failed". The Wizard shows progress in which some of the components including Database Engine could be not be installed.
I need some help related to this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can pop up for a few different scenarios. Do check the logs for error.

One of the scenario  when this error can occur if a Microsoft® system folder is either missing or lacking the correct permissions.

Please use the following steps:

> 1.Click the Windows® Start button and click Run.
>
> 2.Type %appdata% and click OK.
>
> 3.Browse to the Microsoft folder.
>
> 4.Locate the Protect folder to assign the correct permissions:

Note: If the Protect folder is missing from the Microsoft folder, you will need to create it in this location by right-clicking and selecting Folder. Ensure to name the folder "Protect."

> 1.Right-click on the Protect folder and select Properties.
>
> 2.Click on the Security tab. Ensure the System and your logged on Windows User account is listed and both have Full Control.
>
> 3.Click Add to begin adding the accounts. For Windows Vista®/Windows 7, you will need to click Edit first.
>
> 4.In the "Enter the object names to select" box, type the word System, and press Enter on your keyboard. The System account should be listed
> now. Select System from the user names list and select Full Control
> under the Allow column. Click Apply .
>
> 5.Follow steps 3-4 to find, add and assign Full Control permissions also for you logged on Windows User account.
>
> 6.Click OK

.

Attempt to install SQL Server 2008 R2.

Even if this does not solve your problem, you take a look at the msdn blog that provides a workaround for the install scenario and see if this fixes it?

Comment: In Configuration log: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\...Detail.txt i have found the error code to be 24 and error state to be 1306. I have doubt that there may be a conflict between the Service accounts that i had selected for the services in the Server Configuration during Installation. I had chosen Local System as Service Accounts except for the last two options.

Comment: did you try giving the full permissions..?

Comment: Actually i am at workplace. But i will be installing SQL Server 2008 r2 again tonight.I will do the steps you had mentioned above. Then i will tell what would be the output.

Comment: sshekhar i have checked the permissions and SYSTEM and my accounts both have full control permissions. I mean to say that these were the settings i already had when i had tried installing SQL SERVER 2008 r2