# Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL server error log for potential causes

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, installation

I m using SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition. Even I tried SQL Server 2012 Express and Enterprise edition but all gave same error. I browsed msdn blog as well as few post on stackoverflow.

But nothing helped me out from this!

[image: Error Details]

[image: Installation failed]

**Here is the error log details**

```
Overall summary:
Final result:                  Failed: see details below
Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893606
Start time:                    2013-10-21 12:58:05
End time:                      2013-10-21 13:52:30
Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
Next step for RS:              Use the following information to resolve the error,  uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error,  uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  CROY-TOSH
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                       Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

 Package properties:
   Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
   ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
   Type:                          RTM
   Version:                       11
   SPLevel:                       0
   Installation location:         C:\Users\CRoy\Downloads\SQL Server 2012 Developer  Edition (x86 and x64) - DVD (English)\x64\setup\
   Installation edition:          Developer

 Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
 ACTION:                        Install
 ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
 AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
 AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
 AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
 ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL     Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup
 ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AI
 ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL     Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config
 ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL  Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
 ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log
ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService
ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            CRoy-TOSH\CRoy
ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL   Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
CLTCTLRNAME:                   ROY
CLTRESULTDIR:                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL  Server\DReplayClient\ResultDir\
CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                Manual
CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client
CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
CLTWORKINGDIR:                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DReplayClient\WorkingDir\
COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
COMMFABRICPORT:                0
CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131021_125116\ConfigurationFile.ini
CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               Manual
CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller
CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
CTLRUSERS:                     CRoy-TOSH\CRoy
ENABLERANU:                    false
ENU:                           true
ERRORREPORTING:                true
FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ, AS, RS, RS_SHP,  RS_SHPWFE, DQC, BIDS, CONN, IS, BC, SDK, BOL, SSMS, ADV_SSMS, DREPLAY_CTLR, DREPLAY_CLT,  SNAC_SDK, MDS
FILESTREAMLEVEL:               2
FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           MSSQLSERVER
FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
HELP:                          false
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MsDtsServer110
ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
NPENABLED:                     0
PID:                           *****
QUIET:                         false
QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
ROLE:                          <empty>
RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              SharePointFilesOnlyMode
RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\ReportServer
RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
SAPWD:                         *****
SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AI
SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
 SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
 SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
 SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           CRoy-TOSH\CRoy
 SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
 SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
 SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
 SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
 SQMREPORTING:                  false
 TCPENABLED:                    0
 UIMODE:                        Normal
 UpdateEnabled:                 true
 UpdateSource:                  MU
 X86:                           false

 Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131021_125116\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
 Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       SQL Server Data Tools
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
 Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
 Component error code:          0x851A001A
 Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
 Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

 Feature:                       Database Engine Services
 Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
 Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error,  uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
 Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
 Component error code:          0x851A001A
 Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
 Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

 Feature:                       Data Quality Services
 Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
 Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
 Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
 Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
 Component error code:          0x851A001A
 Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
 Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

 Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
 Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
 Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error,  uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

 Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
 Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
 Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
 Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error,  uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
 Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
 Component error code:          0x851A001A
 Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
 Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

 Feature:                       Master Data Services
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Distributed Replay Client
 Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Distributed Replay Controller
  Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Integration Services
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Data Quality Client
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Analysis Services
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Reporting Services - SharePoint
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       SQL Browser
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       Documentation Components
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       SQL Writer
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
 Status:                        Passed

 Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
 Status:                        Passed

 Rules with failures:

 Global rules:

 Scenario specific rules:

 Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131021_125116\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Here is few links

[Blog MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/03/16/sql-2008-r2-setup-fails-with-quot-wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-quot.aspx)

[StackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio)

[StackOverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195300/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed)

Answer (score 65):

Below worked for me:

> When you come to Server Configuration Screen, Change the Account Name of Database Engine Service to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and continue installation and it will successfully install all components without any error. - See more at: 
>   https://superpctricks.com/sql-install-error-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed/

Comment: I used NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. That helped too.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the whole damn thing again and reinstall it all over again? It won't let me just reinstall.

Comment: I used NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and issue resolved.

Comment: This one worked for me too NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. Really I great solution, I spent a lot but didn't get anything useful from microsoft as usual.

Comment: I've reinstalled, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE worked for me.

Comment: I ran into the same thing installing SQL Server 2016.  
I need to set the Database Engine Service to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle No need to reinstall, just run "services.msc", locate SqlServer service, double click and select local account.

Comment: I ran into the same thing. Used AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE but issue was not resolved. I'm using sql 2017 express and Windows 11 OS.

Answer (score 30):

There is a new cause for this error on Windows 11 and newer disks. These new disk have a sector size greater than 4 KB and SQL server can not handle it.

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size)

**Cause**

During service startup, SQL Server begins the database recovery process to ensure database consistency. Part of this database recovery process involves consistency checks on the underlying filesystem before attempting the activity of opening system and user database files.

On systems running Windows 11, some new storage devices and device drivers will expose a disk sector size greater than the supported 4 KB sector size.

When this occurs, SQL Server will be unable to start due to the unsupported file system as SQL Server currently supports sector storage sizes of 512 bytes and 4 KB

You can confirm that you encounter this specific issue by running the command:
Console

```
fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo <volume pathname>
```

Look for the value PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity, returned in bytes. A value of 4096 indicates a sector storage size of 4 KB and can cause this issue.

**Tested resolution**

Command Prompt as Administrator

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t   REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
```

Validate if the key was added successfully.

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes"
```

You can now install `SQL SERVER` as you normally would, without changing accounts.

You might have to restart your computer for a successful installation.

Comment: Will this have an impact on how Windows file system (performance, functionality)?

Comment: I think I found the microsoft realted [Link][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

Comment: After 2 days of searching, Finally!!!. THANK YOU SO MUCH. this worked just fine on windows 11 Enterprise.

Comment: Even SQL server 2022 express/dev preview isn't compatible with Windows 11 out of the box and requires some registry hacks

Comment: This worked in Windows 11 and Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: I opened cmd as admin, ran those commands, and tried to install, but it failed. Then restarted the computer and without doing anything else, tried installing it again: "Installation has completed successfully!" :)

Comment: Thanks you a lot, your guidance really helped me and solved my problem. Win11 22H2 - MSSQL 2022

Comment: This worked for me. I had forgotten to restart the system after the registry edit and directly tried to install SQL Server 2017 on Win 11 Pro. **It failed**. So I did the following steps **1.** Uninstalled SQL Server using Revo Uninstaller (*It's free and better than built-in uninstaller*). It allows you to clean the left over registry keys. **2.** Deleted all files from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` **3.** Restarted the system and then did a fresh install. Installation was successful. It is IMPORTANT that the system is restarted before the installation is attempted...

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, without changing the account to (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE OR NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SYSTEM), Win11 MSSQL 2022

Answer (score 9):

In my case, setting **SQL Server Database Engine service** startup account to **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** failed, but setting it to **NT Authority\System** allowed me to succesfully install my SQL Server 2016 STD instance.

Just check the following snapshot.

[image]

For further details, check @Shanky's answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71798/66179

Remember: you can avoid server rebooting using setup's [SkipRules](https://superuser.com/a/863738/56033) switch:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck

setup.exe /ACTION=UNINSTALL /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck
```

Answer (score 9):

This post is high up when you google that error message, which I got when installing security patch KB4505224 on SQL Server 2017 Express i.e. None of the above worked for me, but did consume several hours trying.

The solution for me, partly from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217762/186591) was:

1. uninstall SQL Server
2. in Regional Settings / Management / System Locale, "Beta: UTF-8 support" should be OFF
3. re-install SQL Server
4. Let Windows install the patch.

And all was well.

More on this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217762/186591).

Comment: It was enough for me repair the installation and kept therefore all databases and settings that I already had. 

This setting is pretty well hidden: Control panel\Clock and Region\Region\Adminstrative tab\Change system locale button \Region Settings

Comment: Awesome, you saved me. Was looking other solutions with User accounts. Would have never think about this. Indeed seems to be link to last build windows 1903

Answer (score 8):

Simple Steps

1. 1 Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Under SQL Server Services Select Your Server
3. Right Click and Select Properties
4. Log on Tab Change Built-in-account tick
5. in the drop down list select Network Service
6. Apply and start The service

Comment: Just the answer I was expecting after 4 hour

Answer (score 7):

### Root cause: Corrupted user profile of user account used to start database

The main thread here seems to be a corrupted user account profile for the account that is used to start the DB engine. This is the account that was specified for the "SQL Server Database" engine during installation. In the setup event log, it's also indicated by the following entry:

```
SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

According to the link provided by [@royki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791056/3063884):

> The root cause of this issue, in most cases, is that the profile of
>   the user being used for the service account (in my case it was local
>   system) is corrupted.

This would explain why other respondents had success after changing to different accounts:

- [bmjjr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738200/3063884) suggests changing to "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
- comments to @bmjjr indicate different accounts *"I used NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. That helped too"*
- [@Julio Nobre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009608/3063884) had success with "NT Authority\System "

### Fix: reset the corrupt user profile

To fix the user profile that's causing the error, follow the steps listed [KB947215](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947215/you-receive-a-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-error-message#letmefixit).

The main steps from KB947215 are summarized as follows:-

1. Open `regedit`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
3. Navigate to the SID for the corrupted profile

   To find the SID, click on each SID GUID, review the value for the `ProfileImagePath` value, and see if it's the correct account. For system accounts, there's a different way to know the SID for the account that failed:

The main *system* account SIDs of interest are:

```
SID          Name               Also Known As
S-1-5-18     Local System       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
S-1-5-19     LocalService       NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
S-1-5-20     NetworkService     NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

For information on additional SIDs, see *[Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems)*.

4. If there are two entries (e.g. with a .bak) at the end for the SID in question, or the SID in question ends in .bak, ensure to follow carefully the steps in the [KB947215](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947215/you-receive-a-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-error-message#letmefixit) article.
5. Reset the values for `RefCount` and `State` to be `0`.
6. Reboot.
7. Retry the SQL Server installation.

Answer (score 1):

It was an error that occurred on windows 11.
I followed the instructions here and it worked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

Remember to restart your computer after that.

I also set account as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

Comment: I found that the registry key solved it. The account change was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried reinstalling different versions again and again (2019, 2022 dev and exp), however initially nothing helped.

1. I tried setting up account numbers NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE & NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SYSTEM.
2. Later executed the command:

   REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t   REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f

Later I was able to install successfully using the similar steps. We just need to keep in mind that, previous installation was failed and that could have some footprints remaining in the system. Hence:

1. Uninstall each instance of previously installed version. And delete all the possible locations (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server). or use **Revo Uninstaller** (http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) to uninstall it completely.
2. Execute the command in administrator mode:

   REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t   REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
3. Set account as **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** while fresh installation.
4. **MOST IMPORTANT:** Restart the system after cleanup and uninstallation process.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above works for me, but found another solution - Install 2019 and upgrade 2022. Works great.