# SQL Server 2016 / 2014 Express Installation Failed

Tags: sql-server

I have tried many times to install SQL Server 2016 or 2014 express on my Windows 10 Pro machine and still occur error message "Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed.". Anyone can advise how to fix it. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**Edit**
I got a summary in "Program Files -> Microsoft SQL Server -> 130 -> Setup Bootstrap -> Log" but no idea what error it claims.

Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Start time:                    2017-08-03 00:19:24
  End time:                      2017-08-03 00:28:51
  Requested action:              Uninstall

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WIN10PRO-PC01
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.15063)
  OS service pack:
  OS region:                     Hong Kong SAR
  OS language:                   English (United Kingdom)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2014      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS             Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS             SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS             Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014      SQLEXPRESS           MSRS12.SQLEXPRESS              Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          SSMS                                     1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Adv_SSMS                                 1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2014                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
  SQL Server 2016      SQLEXPRESS01         MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS01           Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      13.1.4001.0     No         Yes

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation edition:          Express

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Uninstall
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170803_001921\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCEID:                    
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS01
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170803_001921\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170803_001921\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: Both of those errors recommend checking the installation log (or provide the location).  Have you looked at the logs?  What did they say?

Comment: Try these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538089/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-check-the-sql-server-error-l